# Comparing "straightness" of two curves of different dimensionality

Tags: curves, curvature

I apologize in advance for any imprecisions or badly defined concepts that I am not from the field.

I am working with experimental data, so the curves are defined by time series of $d$-dimensional coordinates (i.e. they are "trajectories" in $d$-dimensional spaces). I would like to measure and compare the "straightness" of these trajectories. As a first step, I have arclength reparametrized the trajectories such that consecutive points are at unit distance along the trajectory.

My current method is using the method from [this post.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/98111)
That is:

1. Get the tangent vector $\vec T_n =\frac{ x_{n+1} - x_n }{\lVert  x_{n+1} - x_n \rVert}  $  for all $n-1$ points $x$ where $x$ are $d$-dimensional coordinates.
2. Sum $\lVert \vec T_{n+1} - \vec T_n \rVert $ for all $n-2$ tangent vectors $\vec T$.
3. Divide the sum of 2. by total arclength.

If my interpretation is right, this should gives me a measure of how much the direction change along the curves, and thus how straight it is.

However, I am afraid that comparing the straightness of trajectories lying in space of different number of dimensions might introduce bias in this metric.

Is it possible (as in, well defined) to compare the straightness of space curves if they are embedded in space of different dimensions ?

EDIT: Added more details and changed "curvature" to "straightness".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I have edited my question to make it more specific. If still unclear, please specify which parts are, as I am not from the field so what seems clear to me might be obscure to people here.

Comment: "Consecutive points"? You can talk about total curvature or average curvature of curves no matter where they live. The question is: What does comparing them mean? They're just numbers.

Comment: This comment is not helpful and does not address my question. Average curvature is not "just a number" as it gives information on how twisted is a curve. A straight line and an 'S' like curve do not have the same average curvature.

Comment: Comments are not supposed to be "helpful" to you. That is what *answers* are for. The main purpose of comments is to clarify the poster's intent and address other issues in the post. You have not provided enough detail for us to be clear what it is you want. The original post is just a generic message (note the "Bot" after the Community name - this was not a real person, though likely it was generated because some moderator flagged it). Ted Shifrin is being more specific about where the problem lies. First you talk about "consecutive points" and "derivatives", which are contradictory concepts.

Comment: Then you talk about comparing curvatures of different curves without making it clear what sort of comparison you are doing. Because this we are not sure what answer would be best. You can always compare numbers. But that comparison may be meaningless. We don't know enough about what you want to decide what comparison would be meaningful for your purpose. A circle of the same radius drawn in any dimensional space will have the same curvature.  However, in 2 dimensions, pointwise curvature completely describes the curve up to an isometry. But in higher dimensions it does not.

Comment: A helical spiral has constant curvature, but is not a circle. It also has *torsion*, which a two-dimensional curve cannot support. In higher dimensions, curves have torsion in multiple directions.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments @PaulSinclair . I have now edited my question to meke it (hopefully) more understandable. "You can always compare numbers. But that comparison may be meaningless." This is exactly what I am trying to express in my question.